# keep a formless application from closing for a keyboard hook

Tags: c++, winapi, keyboard, hook

I am working on a c++ win32 program that involves a keyboard hook. The application is a win32 project with no user interface whatsoever. I need to keep the application from closing without using causing the hook to not work or use up a bunch of system resources. I used to use a message box but I need the application to be completely invisible.

Any help would be appreciated!

If you have any questions just ask.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think what you need is [message only window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632599(VS.85).aspx#message_only)

> (***MSDN says***) A message-only window enables you to send and receive messages. It is not visible, has no z-order, cannot be enumerated, and does not receive broadcast messages. The window simply dispatches messages.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need windows?
The [MSDN LowLevelKeyboardProc page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644985%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) recommends using a simple message loop.
Just insert this snippet after the hook call.

```
// message loop to keep the keyboard hook running
MSG msg;
while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

A better way would be to add an loop that keeps going around.

```
bool shouldExit = false;

do
{
   //some code to handle events
   shouldExit = handleEvents();

   //sleep for a small bit so we dont take up 100% cpu
   sleep(500);
}
while (!shouldExit);
```